# WP theme built on Twitter Bootstrap - need fixed navbar for code that doesn't use ".navbar"

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, fixed

I've got a WP theme built on TB. I'd like to make the menu navigation fixed at the top of the screen when scrolling. The creator didn't use the navbar class for the menu. Instead there's a #menu id, so using the usual navbar-fixed-top solution doesn't work. Here's the markup for the header below. I'm hoping someone can shed some light on how I can accomplish this, especially if it can be done using CSS customization. I'm new to all this, so please forgive any misuse of terms and correct me. Thanks very much!

```
<header style="opacity: 1; margin-top: 0px; ">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

    <div class="span3">
    <div id="logo">
            <a href="SITE URL">

                                    </a>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span9">
        <!-- Mobile Menu -->
        <a id="mobile-nav" class="menu-nav" href="#menu-nav"><span class="menu-icon"></span></a>

        <!-- Standard Menu -->
        <div id="menu">
            <ul id="menu-nav" class="sf-js-enabled">
            <li id="menu-item-14" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-9 current_page_item menu-item-14"><a href="SITE URL">Home<mark class="bar"></mark></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-266" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-266"><a href="SITE URL?page_id=252">About<mark class="bar"></mark></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-13" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-13"><a href="SITE URL?page_id=11">Blog<mark class="bar"></mark></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-198" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-198"><a href="SITE URL?page_id=196">SITE NAME<mark class="bar"></mark></a>
<ul class="sub-menu sf-js-enabled" style="float: none; width: 20em; display: none; visibility: hidden; ">
<li id="menu-item-569" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-portfolio menu-item-569" style="white-space: normal; float: none; width: 100%; "><a href="SITE NAME?portfolio=PAGE" style="float: none; width: auto; ">PAGE NAME<mark class="bar"></mark></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-565" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-portfolio menu-item-565" style="white-space: normal; float: none; width: 100%; "><a href="SITE NAME?portfolio=PAGE" style="float: none; width: auto; ">PAGE NAME<mark class="bar"></mark></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-454" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-portfolio menu-item-454" style="white-space: normal; float: none; width: 100%; "><a href="SITE NAME?portfolio=PAGE" style="float: none; width: auto; ">PAGE NAME<mark class="bar"></mark></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-265" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-265"><a href="SITE URL?page_id=257">Contact<mark class="bar"></mark></a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally after weeks of searching and trying out solutions to create a fixed navigation/menu bar in the Banshee theme, I've found it. For anyone else who's been trying to figure this out, I'm posting it below. The reason it's so difficult to find is that Banshee doesn't use the option built into Twitter Bootstrap (navbar-fixed-top). Instead, it uses the header as the part to alter to get this to work.

```
header {
position: fixed; 
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
text-center;
background: #d6c493;
 -webkit-box-shadow:  0px -2px 8px 2px #424756;
 box-shadow:  0px -2px 8px 2px #424756;
 z-index:999;
}

@media (min-width : 980px) {
#main {
padding-top: 80px;
}
}
```

EDIT: Someone else suggested the @media section so I could delete the top margin I had, and it works great.

This code also puts a subtle drop shadow under the header as well. Values of the header height and margin-top will have to be experimented with to make it work for individual sites in case that's been altered from the theme's defaults (mine was altered). The usual TB recommendation of adding padding to the body does not work with this solution since it doesn't use the navbar-fixed-top class.

Hope this helps someone else out. But…

NEW PROBLEM:

With the fixed menu, when I use a jQuery slider (Revolution Slider) the image placement is fine under the menu at desktop viewing size, but once I start resizing the window smaller, the images resize smaller, but start moving up under the fixed menu. I can't find a way to get them to stay in position under the menu. If I add any padding at all, even if I specify just for the top, it seems to always increase the space between the slider's bottom and the body. This is a responsive theme and the images are resizing responsively.

Help, please. Many thanks to anyone who takes a look.